# Cheapest graphics card for starcraft

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards

I am looking for a graphics card that can run Starcraft II at 1080p and 60 fps. I know that it isn't a super graphics heavy game and am ideally looking for something under $100. I would like something that has linux support as well but most major graphics card manufacturers have that.

I haven't decided what CPU I am going to buy yet but I am planing to buy a pretty powerful one so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already purchased anything, it is entirely possible for an APU to provide you with the processing AND graphics power you need to run the game well. Given that StarCraft II is not highly threaded, but that unfortunately Intel refuses to put any worthy GPU on anything below an i5, I recommend something like the A10-7890K, which at ~150 represents a $75 CPU combined with a $75 GPU and pretty much performs like it, too. Just be sure to pair it with 2133 or 2400mhz RAM.

Alternatively, get whatever CPU you want and pair it with a GPU like the R7 250X or GTX 750; either one is powerful enough for SCII in spades.